# Having Issues with Django on Windows Vista

Tags: django, command-line, window

I installed subversion, which seemed to install Python25, which my computer won't let me erase, or even recognize as a program on the control panel. I copied my Python27 Python.py file into the Python 25 folder to replace Python.py (the Python 25 version), and got my command prompt to run Python 27 (even though I had specified the Python 27 folder, it insisted on running Python 25). I copied the Django trunk into the site-packages of Django 27 and Django 25. Import Django works in Python, but now I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Users\Susan\Documents\practice

C:\Users\Susan\Documents\practice>django-admin.py startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\csvn\Python25\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.core import management
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError, handle_de
fault_options
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 2, in
 <module>
import urllib
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\socket.py", line 45, in <module>
import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python25.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

Thanks in advance.

Oh, and this is my environment path variable: C:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Python27;C\Python27\scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\

And this is my python variable: C:\Python27;C\Python27\scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\

---

EDIT: realized that USER path wasn't the same as System path. Made them both the same, now receiving this message:

```
C:\Users\Susan\Documents\practice>django-admin.py startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 2
,     in <module>
    from django.core import management
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError, handle_de
 fault_options
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 2, in
<module>
   import urllib
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\socket.py", line 45, in <module>
    import _socket
```

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Why does it keep trying to use Python25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would un-install Python 2.7 and 2.5 from your machine and re-inistall Python 2.7. You'll have to have a working Python install before you can think about installing Django.

After that's working, I would recommend installing [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/) and [Justin Driscoll's virtualenv helper for Windows](http://justindriscoll.us/2009/03/virtualenv-helper-for-windows.html).

Virtualenv allows you to create different Python runtimes so you don't have to install modules directly into the system Python Path. Installing virtualenv gets you pip, which you can use to install modules like Django, into your virtualenv's site-packages folder.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was able to help you out.